# Excel Add-in: How to create a range?

Tags: javascript, excel, range, selection, office-js

I am writing an Excel add-in in JavaScript.

What I need to do is find the currently selected cell, then create a range object that is 4 columns wide and X rows high, with the selected cell at the top left of the selection.

I know how to find the currently selected cell, but I don't know how to either expand that selection or create a new range that is the size I need.

Any assistance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The beta Excel.js has a method that does exactly what you want:

```
rangeObject.getAbsoluteResizedRange(numRows, numColumns);
```

If rangeObject is the currently selected cell, then
`rangeObject.getAbsoluteResizedRange(3, 4);`

will return a 3 by 4 range with the currently selected cell in the upper left.

In latest production Excel.js, you could use `range.getCell()` method to get a reference to the desired lower right cell. Then call `range.getBoundingRect()` and pass the lower right range to it. For info about these, see [Range](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/range).

**UPDATE 1/1/22**: getAbsoluteResizedRange is no longer in preview. You can use it in a production add-in.

Comment: To add to Ricky's answer:  alternatively, do `workbook.getSelectedRange().getCell(0,0).getResizedRange(rowCount - 1, columnCount - 1)`

Comment: I used the getCell() and getBoundingRect() and they worked like a charm. Thanks!